# Catalog: Custom Product Collection, mode switch (grid/list) bug?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, frontend, product-collection, pagination

**Edit:** I think I found a solution. (See answer by me below)

I have a product collection which I pass to the Magento `catalog/product_list` block. I've set `curPage` and `pageSize` of the collection and pagination is working fine except the weird behavior I try to describe below.

In my case I have **15** products.

```
Default View Mode = Grid
Products per Page on Grid = 12 (Default Value)
Products per Page on List = 10 (Default Value)
```

When I view my collection in the catalog(frontend), default view mode is Grid, and I change the limit (Products per Page) to 24, all 15 products are shown on the first page. So far so good. But when I switch mode to `list` it shows me all 15 products on the first page but it also gives the possibility to go to the second page which contains the same 15 products.

Here my code:

```
    $curPage = 1;
    $mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode');
    $grid_products_per_page = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page_values'));
    $list_products_per_page = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page_values'));

    //Default Values
    if($mode == 'grid' || $mode == 'grid-list') {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
    } else {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');
    }


    $mode = ($_GET['mode'] != null ? $_GET['mode'] : $mode);
    $pageSize = ($_GET['limit'] != null ? $_GET['limit'] : $pageSize);
    $curPage = ($_GET['p'] != null ? $_GET['p'] : $curPage);


    //Supposed to handle mode switch
    if($mode == 'grid') {
        $pageSize = $this->getClosestNumber($pageSize, $grid_products_per_page);
    } elseif($mode == 'list') {
        $pageSize = $this->getClosestNumber($pageSize, $list_products_per_page);        
    }

    /*
     * Fill product_result_ids array...
     */

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addIdFilter($product_result_ids);
    $productCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $productCollection->setCurPage($curPage);
    $productCollection->count();   

    //The numbers seem to be correct
    echo $productCollection->count().'<br />';
    echo $curPage.'<br />';
    echo $pageSize.'<br />'; 

    return $productCollection;
```

If any more information is needed, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. This is how it seems to work:

```
$curPage = 1;
$mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode');
$grid_products_per_page = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page_values'));
$list_products_per_page = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page_values'));

//Default Values
if($mode == 'grid' || $mode == 'grid-list') {
    $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
} else {
    $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');
}


$mode = ($_GET['mode'] != null ? $_GET['mode'] : $mode);
$pageSize = ($_GET['limit'] != null ? $_GET['limit'] : $pageSize);
$curPage = ($_GET['p'] != null ? $_GET['p'] : $curPage);


//Supposed to handle mode switch (Changed part)
if($mode == 'grid' || $mode == 'grid-list') {
    if(in_array($pageSize, $grid_products_per_page) == false) {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
    }
} elseif($mode == 'list' || $mode == 'list-grid') {
    if(in_array($pageSize, $list_products_per_page) == false) {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');
    }
}

/*
 * Fill product_result_ids array...
 */

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIdFilter($product_result_ids);
$productCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
$productCollection->setCurPage($curPage);
$productCollection->count();   

//The numbers seem to be correct
echo $productCollection->count().'<br />';
echo $curPage.'<br />';
echo $pageSize.'<br />'; 

return $productCollection;
```

To get this to work I had to observe the behavior of the toolbar a bit.
If you are in catalog view and switch from `grid mode` to `list mode` (or other way around) the toolbar(not sure which class) checks if the `$_GET['limit']` value is in the `products_per_page` array of the corresponding mode (grid or list). If not it picks the default value of this mode. I had to do it the same way to make sure the `pageSize` of my collection is synchronized with the toolbar.

```
if($mode == 'grid' || $mode == 'grid-list') {
    if(in_array($pageSize, $grid_products_per_page) == false) {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
    }
} elseif($mode == 'list' || $mode == 'list-grid') {
    if(in_array($pageSize, $list_products_per_page) == false) {
        $pageSize = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');
    }
}
```